# Angular Scope ng-model changes dont affect the textbox value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I spent a day to figure out why when I change the ng-model inside my controller, the value of the text box doest change.

HTML :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="address" />
```

JS :

```
function func1()
{
    $scope.address = "SOME VALUE";
}
```

but finally I get rid of this error by doing this :

HTML :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="temp.address" />
```

Controller :

```
$scope.temp = {

    address : ""

}

function func1()
{
    $scope.temp.address = "SOME VALUE";
}
```

In the second code, the textbox gets the value and it works properly.This is happening while the other binding values like `ngRepeats` or `ngChanges` or `ngClick` on the page are working properly

Any idea why?

Comment: Did you declare `$scope.address` outside of `function func1()` like you did with `$scope.temp`?

Comment: @Hoyen , no i didn't , does it matter?

Comment: Is the `ng-model` inside `ng-if` or any other directive?

Comment: @FrankModica no , the code is pretty simple like what i mentioned in my question

Comment: @FrankModica no I was wrong, I just check the codes and I noticed the textbox is inside a ng-if ? but ng-if effects the both codes i mentioned in my question at the same way

Comment: Read up on prototypal inheritance and how it affects AngularJS bindings, and why it is generally advised to have a dot when using `ng-model` (i.e. bind to an object property).

Comment: @FrankModica I didn't know that. well, I hadn't such this issue in my other page in any other projects. so if I'm not mistaken you mean it's recommended you use an object for ng-model? is it like a bug or something in angularjs ? in my site yes it is.